# Посчитать сложность алгоритма C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сложность

Как правильно посчитать сложность алгоритма? Смотрю все примеры, которые есть на stackoverflow и все равно никак не пойму.

Сам алгоритм С#:

```
   class Program
{
    static int sum(int mas_kol)
    {
        int sum_arr = 0;
        int[] mas = new int[mas_kol];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            if ((mas[i] % 2 != 0) && (mas[i] < 0))
                sum_arr += mas[i];
        }
        return sum_arr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов в массиве: ");
        int mas_kol = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма нечетных и отрицательных элементов = " + sum(mas_kol));
    }
}
```

Как я правильно понял - получается линейная сложность? Но как к такому выводу придти правильно?

Comment: А вы не смотрите примеры, а почитайте лучше толковые книги. Итоговую сложность поняли правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в коде один цикл по всем элементам массива. Рекурсии нет, вложенных циклов нет, досрочного выхода из цикла тоже нет. Поэтому сложность `O(n)` - линейная.

Comment: И что важно: внутри цикла все функции выполняющиеся за константное время.

Comment: @AK Но даже если бы и не за константное. Если время исполнения каждой из функций внутри цикла никак не зависит от `n`, разве это как-то повлияет на оценку сложности алгоритма?

Comment: @CrazyElf Значит, все я правильно понял. Спасибо! Нам дали пример с квадратичной сложностью, получается, что мне просто ничего не нужно считать, а просто в качестве ответа указать O(n)? Спасибо за точные пояснения.

`S=a^n+b^n
T(N) = N1^n+N2^n
T(N) = O(N^2) - квадратичная сложность.`

Comment: @ArtemL. С формулами я вам не подскажу, у меня чисто инженерный анализ )

Comment: Если оно не будет зависеть от N, но будет пропорционально какому-то M - то да, повлияет, надо будет перемножать. Мы с вами просто оба посмотрели на функции и увидели, что там всё константно, не зависит от N и типа пренебрегли эффектом. Но а если бы в цикле стоял бы какой-то поиск строки длиной M - пришлось бы учесть.

Comment: @AK Так `O(N)` не учитывает константы. Вот если бы `M` зависело как-то от `N`, например было бы пропорционально `log(N)`, тогда да, было бы `O(N*log(N))`. А если это константа, независящая от `N`, то ведь всё-равно будет `O(N)`.